# Formula for Finding residue

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

[image]

Can some one please provide how is this possible? and does it work with double poles?

Comment: Have you tried checking Cauchy's Residue formula?  And by double poles you mean poles of order 2?

Answer (score 5):

Both sides are zero if $g(z_0)=0$, so assume that $g(z_0)\neq 0$. Since $h$ has a simple zero, $f$ has a simple pole at $z_0$, hence
$$ \mathrm{Res}_{z_0}f=\lim_{z\to z_0}(z-z_0)f(z)=\lim_{z\to z_0}g(z)\frac{z-z_0}{h(z)-h(z_0)}=\frac{g(z_0)}{h^{\prime}(z_0)}$$

This formula relies on $h(z)$ having a simple zero at $z_0$. For instance, if $h(z)$ has a zero of order $2$ at $z_0$ (and $g(z_0)\neq 0$), then
$$ \mathrm{Res}_{z_0}f=\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{d}{dz}\Big[(z-z_0)^2\frac{g(z)}{h(z)}\Big]$$
which doesn't simplify as nicely.